# xml to linq, how to fix late binding?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I'm searching in a xml file for specific elements, I have come up with an a okay solution which will find the elements I need, however, if I were to turn on the Option Strict the compiler will tell me it doesn't allow late binding.  A quick search on the internet lead me to that the binding needs to be initialized as a type before execution, just not exactly sure on how to go about that.

I can simply leave the option off, but for the sake of better coding, I wanted to leave it on and see how I can avoid late binding.  I am honestly not sure where to even start, do I need a class with its own properties?

```
Dim xmlDocument As String = "C:\***\comp.xml"  ' Path '
Dim xelement As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlDocument)
Console.WriteLine("What company are you searching for? ")
searchCompData = Console.ReadLine()

Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Object) = From c In xelement.Descendants("COMPANYINFO").Descendants("Office")
                                        Where CType(c.Parent.Parent.Element("compId"), String) = searchCompData
                                        Select New With
                                        {
                                            .reg = c.Parent.Element("Region"),
                                            .city = c.Parent.Element("City"),
                                            .ceo = c.Parent.Element("CEO"),
                                            .office = c
                                        }

For Each res As Object In results
    Console.WriteLine(res.reg)
    Console.WriteLine(res.city)
    Console.WriteLine(res.ceo)
    Console.WriteLine(res.office)
Next
Console.ReadLine()
```

My example xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CompType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CompanyRegion>
    <compId>1</compId>
    <compRegionId>654</compRegionId>
    <compTransPort>Van</compTransPort>
    <COMPANYINFO>
      <compInfoId>545</compInfoId>
      <City>London</City>
      <Zip>3214</Zip>
      <Zone>535</Zone>
      <Region>London Region</Region>
      <LocalNumber>54687874</LocalNumber>
      <CEO>Alice Goldsmith</CEO>
      <CompanyStreet>BongoBingo St</CompanyStreet>
      <Office>
        <Name>IT</Name>
        <Place>2nd Floor</Place>
        <Manager>
          <Name>Steven Smith</Name>
          <Address>Robo Street</Address>
          <Phonenumber>12345</Phonenumber>
        </Manager>
      </Office>
      <Office>
        <Name>Accountants</Name>
        <Place>3d Floor</Place>
        <Manager>
          <Name>Joana Petersen</Name>
          <Address>Lamba Street</Address>
          <Phonenumber>54321</Phonenumber>
        </Manager>
      </Office>
    </COMPANYINFO>
  </CompanyRegion>
  <CompanyRegion>
    <compId>2</compId>
    <compRegionId>785</compRegionId>
    <compTransPort>Truck</compTransPort>
    <COMPANYINFO>
      <compInfoId>321</compInfoId>
      <City>Oslo</City>
      <Zip>4598</Zip>
      <Zone />
      <Region>Oslo Region</Region>
      <LocalNumber>458754121</LocalNumber>
      <CEO>Michael Jonson</CEO>
      <CompanyStreet>BingoBango St</CompanyStreet>
      <Office>
        <Name>Sales</Name>
        <Place>4th Floor</Place>
        <Manager>
          <Name>Rachel Laurensen</Name>
          <Address>Albo Street</Address>
          <Phonenumber>55555</Phonenumber>
        </Manager>
      </Office>
      <Office>
        <Name>Accountants</Name>
        <Place>1st Floor</Place>
        <Manager>
          <Name>Peter Carlsen</Name>
          <Address>Lobo Street</Address>
          <Phonenumber>455656</Phonenumber>
        </Manager>
      </Office>
    </COMPANYINFO>
  </CompanyRegion>
</CompType>
```

Comment: Exactly which part does it complain about?

Comment: If you use Option Infer On and then change `Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Object) =` to `Dim results =` and `For Each res As Object In results` to `For Each res In results` is it happy?

Comment: It's complaining about the res.reg etc, saying it doesn't allow late binding, if I were to remove .reg, it would be fine.

Comment: Actually, your answer helped, by turning option infer on and changing results as ienumerable(of objects) to Dim results = , thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`As IEnumerable(Of Object)` can be removed for the anonymous type to be inferred, and `.Value` is needed to get element values. Also, [VB.Net XML axis properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/accessing-xml) can be used to simplify the query :

```
Dim results = From c In xelement...<CompanyRegion> 
              Where c.<compId>.Value = searchCompData
              Select New With {
                  .reg = c...<Region>.Value,
                  .city = c...<City>.Value,
                  .ceo = c...<CEO>.Value,
                  .office = c...<Office>
              }
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution looks better, I can't upvote as I am new, sorry.